# No power to media display

Tags: ford, audio, focus

I have a 2016 Ford Focus we bought at auction, so I have no history. The radio/media display seems to have no power. We had it tested by the dealership and they said it needed a new screen. We replaced that and still it seems that power is not getting to the unit. We have power to the heat and AC and we have power to the hazard button in the same area. But nothing to the screen or stereo in general. I’ve checked the fuse and it is fine. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?  Do I need to take it back to the dealership?

Comment: Have you checked for power on the power connectors on the back of the media unit?

Comment: It would be useful if you added some photos of the media unit both front and rear.

Answer (score 1):

It is very common for the stereo/cd unit behind the bezel to be the fail point in this vehicle. It is an internal electrical failure which affects radio/cd/media/sync/info functions. New replacement from the dealership could cost you upwards of $600. I personally recommend getting a used one from an wrecking yard if available, generally costing less than $50. Also they are very easy to swap out with little skill and simple tools which would save you even more $. There several decent YouTube videos on this procedure. Hope this helps.